# useState data:null after fetching API data and set to useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My purpose is to create a fetching function and return useState Data and use this function in other component.

It's fine to console.log (response.data).
However, when I console.log useState "Data" it's show nothing after fetching data.
Can anybody tell me why and how to solve it?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState} from "react";


const FetchPost = async () => {

    const [Data, setData] = useState(null)

    try {
        const response = await axios.get('url/api/blogs')
        .then(console.log(response.data))
        .then(setData(response.data))
        console.log (`this is useState data:${Data}`) 
        
      } 
      
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }

      return Data  
}

export default FetchPost
```

Comment: You should console outside of try catch, first your see null and then a value in data

Comment: If you are looking for same api call for other components then you can create custom hook and simply call it

Comment: Oh I noticed a mistake

Comment: You can't use await and then simultaneously like this

Answer (score 0):

You can't use await & then together. Please replace your try-catch code with  the below-

```js
try {
        const response = await axios.get('url/api/blogs')
        console.log(response);
        setData(response.data) 
        
      } 
      
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
```

> Now, console.log(Data) outside of try-catch. First you will see null &
> then a value in Data.

Comment: In my concept,  when I put the fetching data into the setData function, suppose react will re-render the component and then update the value. Am I wrong??

Comment: Yes, right.You can  put your fetching function inside setData

Comment: I hope the answer I have shared above solves your problem.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your time answer my question. However, I try to use your code but it return null 2 times as well....

Comment: can you tell me output of console.log(response)?

Comment: below is the console.log(response)

{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245798/discussion-between-king-yip-and-gulshan-aggarwal).

Answer (score 0):

make sure to run your `FetchPost()` function insie a `useEffect` hook wherever you are calling it, example :

```
useEffect(()=>{
    FetchPost();
  },[]);
```